# Как расположить TextView на всю ширину TableRow внутри TableLayout?

Tags: android

Как расположить `TextView` на всю ширину `TableRow` внутри `TableLayout`?
Всего в каждом `TableRow` по три `TextView`, но внизу и вверху по одному, ширина первого столбца определяется в том числе по `TextView`, расположенными в первой и последней строчке `TableRow`.
Как это исправить?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос разметку.

Comment: Layout weight не помогает?

Comment: таблица строится программно, разметки нет

Comment: TextView.setWieght когда задаешь, все равно следующий TextView на уровне второго столбца получается

Comment: мне необходимо задать android:layout_span, чтобы TextView занимал  две ячейки, но как это сделать в JAVA ???

Comment: Разметки нет, но код-то есть - его и показывайте. `android:layout_span` можно задать через `TableRow.LayoutParams`